# Error in round(sw.fit, 2): non-numeric argument to mathematical function Traceback:

Tags: r, linearmodels

I know there are several answered questions regarding this error in R. However, I was not able to find one that could help me in my case.

What I am trying to do is fit a multiple linear model in it and rounding the output that I get into 2 decimal places. However, I get this error:

[image: error message]

This is what I have used to fit the model:

```
sw.fit <- step(lm.fit, k = log(nrow(train)), trace = 0, direction = 'both')
```

and this is what I used to round to 2 decimal places:

```
sw.fit<- round(sw.fit,2)
```

and this is the error I get:

```
Error in round(sw.fit, 2): non-numeric argument to mathematical function
Traceback:
```

Could you please help me figure out what I am doing wrong here?

I appreciate your help, thank you in advance!

Comment: If you check `class(sw.fit)`, you'll se that it is not `numeric`, but `lm` (linear model). You must first extract the relevant coefficients you want to round before you `round()`

Comment: If might be helpful to look at `coef` or `summary` of your result.

Comment: `coef(sw.fit)` will give you the coefficient.

Comment: Hi all, I finally managed to round it by doing:  print(round(coeff, digits = 2))